# Retrieve data from post call from an external service in SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sapui5

We've developed a custom SAP UI5 application and it's deployed into an external portal(with the direct standalone link of UI5 application). As per the configuration of the portal w.r.t this UI5 application, it generates a tokenId which we need to retrieve in our application for further authentication process.
So, the token is being passed to the index.html of the UI5 application through a POST call and I'm able to see it through the developer tools under "Form Data" in the Firefox browser.

Can anyone help me retrieving this tokenId into my ui5 application's index.html file with some code examples. Tried with various techniques through javascript, but none of them worked. The overall flow of the application is as follows:

1. User logs into the portal.
2. Clicks on the link for UI5 application
3. A new tab will be opened with the URL of ui5 application, along with the token being sent by POST call.

Attaching the image for reference..
[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

URLs that open in tabs will open as GET requests. If you want to send the token, I think you're going to have to send it as a query parameter on the URL. You can then retrieve them using [jQuery.sap.getUriParameters()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.getUriParameters)

Comment: Hi Jewett, thanks for replying. Here, tokenId is something confidential and the client doesn't want it be shown on the url of the browser. So we are looking for any options on how to retrieve it's value from the POST call only.

Comment: Then you need a server-side app you can post to. Anything in the browser is accessible to the user, so if the tokenId is confidential then you cannot make it accessible to the UI5 app without making it available to the user.

Comment: Hey Jewett, we had slightly altered our design. As the client(browser) won't be able to handle the post call, I've developed a BSP application in which the token is received. When user clicks the link on the portal it redirects to our new BSP app along with posting the token. Now this BSP has to forward this token to our UI5 application. Can you suggest me the best way to achieve it?